# Login popup window - issue sending event or message to parent

Tags: javascript, extjs, spotify

I'm using Extjs and Java. The Spotify user login is carried out in a browser popup window and I have all of the auth process working correctly.

I need to tell the parent window that the login was successful and then close the window.

However I have an issue after processing the client login - any listeners I place on the parent window do no pick up events or messages from the popup window.

Although if the user is already logged in then the listeners **do work** when the window completes the process.

Any clues as to why the Spotify redirects/login process break the listeners/events would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I set a listener on the parent window to listen for a message event from the child, which works.

On the parent:

```
var width = 450,
height = 400,
left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

var w = window.open('http://localhost:8080',
    'MyWindow',
    'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
);

 window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

 function receiveMessage(event)
 {
     if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:8080") {
         return;
     }
     console.log('User logged in');
     window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
     w.close();
     // more logic...
  }
```

On the child window:

```
this.opener.postMessage("User logged in", "*");
```